# Android - Update process on google play store

Tags: android, google-play

I need to update an app that is already available for download on Google Play Store. Before the official submit I would like to be able to validate that my app is working correctly. I have this message when I want to push the new version:

> This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
>
> All devices that might receive version 1 would receive version 2.
>
> Some devices are eligible to run multiple APKs. In such a scenario,
>   the device will receive the APK with the higher version code.

For what I read here, I'll need to disable the first version before being able to submit the 2nd version.

One question remains unanswered for me: When disabling my first version, does that make it unavailable to users for download?

I don't want to break something in the current version, but I want to validate that my split package (.apk + .obb) is working correctly before I push the "Publish" button.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

You can download your current package from the Play Store and then manually update your app by installing your new signed APK. That process mimics a Play Store update.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a new version, you can upload it without publishing it. This will allow you to make sure things are good. You do not have to take the existing version off of the store before doing so.

In your case, I'd recommend uploading a beta APK file, creating a google group, and testing it there. People have to specifically sign up for the beta, so you probably won't get a whole lot of people. You can sign yourself up for the beta distribution, make sure you get the right version, and then commit the beta version to the published version.